# Pyton. Функция возвращает переменную 'generator'

Tags: python, типы-данных, генераторы

Начало обучения. Есть задачка по написанию функции, которая возвращает сезон в зависимости от номера месяца на входе функции.

Я создал словарь и написал следующую функцию:

```
def vr_goda(mon):
    seasons = {'winter': [1, 2, 12], 'spring': [3, 4, 5], 'summer': [6, 7, 8], 'fall': [9, 10, 11]}
    for i in seasons.keys():   # Данный блок хочу заменить на однострочное выражение
        if mon in seasons[i]:  
            return i

print(vr_goda(3)) # 'spring'
```

Здесь я хотел применить однострочное выражение

```
return (i for i in seasons.keys() if mon in seasons[i])
```

Однако при вызове результата функции она возвращает тип 'generator'
`<generator object vr_goda.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000000001D57B88>`

Как получить необходимое значение - наименование ключа?

Comment: замените круглые скобки квадратными.

Answer (score 2):

Вариантов несколько.

1. Генерировать список и взять от него нулевой элемент (хоть он там и так будет единственным).

```
    return [i for i in seasons if mon in seasons[i]][0]
```

2. Оставить генератор, но, опять же, достать из него элемент при помощи функции `next()`.

```
    return next(i for i in seasons if mon in seasons[i])
```

P.S. И метод `.keys()` использовать не обязательно.

Answer (score 0):

Есть несколько вариантов решения.

#### Преобразование к списку

Использовать квадратные скобки или метод `list` для того чтобы получить список, а не генератор. И доставать первый элемент, чтобы получить значение.

```
return list(i for i in seasons.keys() if mon in seasons[i])[0]
```

Если список получится пустым, то попытка достать несуществующий элемент выдаст исключение `IndexError`.

#### Использование функции `next`

Для того чтобы не преобразовывать в список, можно использовать [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next), которая получает следующий элемент из генератора.

```
return next(i for i in seasons.keys() if mon in seasons[i])
```

Если элемента не будет найдено, то будет выдано исключение `StopIteration`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def vr_goda(mon):
    seasons = {'winter': [1, 2, 12], 'spring': [3, 4, 5], 'summer': [6, 7, 8], 'fall': [9, 10, 11]}
    for i in seasons.keys():  # Данный блок хочу заменить на однострочное выражение
        if mon in seasons[i]:
            return i


print(f'{vr_goda(3) = }')


def vr_goda_mod(mon):
    seasons = {'winter': [1, 2, 12], 'spring': [3, 4, 5], 'summer': [6, 7, 8], 'fall': [9, 10, 11]}
    # Заменили
    return (i for i in seasons.keys() if mon in seasons[i])


season, = vr_goda_mod(5)
print(f'{season = }')


def vr_goda_1(mon):
    seasons = {'winter': [1, 2, 12], 'spring': [3, 4, 5], 'summer': [6, 7, 8], 'fall': [9, 10, 11]}
    for k, v in seasons.items():
        if mon in v:
            return k


def vr_goda_2(mon):
    from itertools import dropwhile
    seasons = {'winter': [1, 2, 12], 'spring': [3, 4, 5], 'summer': [6, 7, 8], 'fall': [9, 10, 11]}

    return dropwhile(lambda x: mon not in seasons.get(x), seasons.keys())


def vr_goda_3(mon):
    seasons = {'winter': [1, 2, 12], 'spring': [3, 4, 5], 'summer': [6, 7, 8], 'fall': [9, 10, 11]}

    return filter(lambda x: mon in seasons.get(x), seasons.keys())


season_1 = vr_goda_1(11)
season_2, *_ = vr_goda_2(5)
season_3, = vr_goda_3(2)
print(
    f'{season_1 = }',
    f'{season_2 = }',
    f'{season_3 = }',
    sep='\n'
)
```

Вывод:

```latex
vr_goda(3) = 'spring'
season = 'spring'
season_1 = 'fall'
season_2 = 'spring'
season_3 = 'winter'
```

#### Но я бы сделал так

```py
def seasons(mon):
    return {
        1: 'winter',
        2: 'winter',
        3: 'spring',
        4: 'spring',
        5: 'spring',
        6: 'summer',
        7: 'summer',
        8: 'summer',
        9: 'fall',
        10: 'fall',
        11: 'fall',
        12: 'winter'
    }.get(mon)
```